# HTML5 - Attach image to mail using Java EE

Tags: javascript, html, email, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I am developing an a drawing application using Javascript.

Users will be able to draw on a canvas. Once they are done with drawing, they will be able to convert it into an image (Convert to image button).

This is the code:

```
function putImage()
{
  var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas");        
  if (canvas1.getContext) 
  { 
    var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");  
    var myImage = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");
  }
  var imageElement = document.getElementById("MyPix"); 
  imageElement.src = myImage; 
  $('#submit_btn').closest('.ui-btn').show(); 
}
```

There's a submit button and when the users click on it, the application will redirect to another page whereby the user will be able to send an email (using java mail) with the image attached to it. 
The page allows user to type in the email address that they wanna send to, and the body of the email.

May i know how to make the image auto-attach to the email so that the after the user type in the email address and the body, they will be able to send the mail?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To send the image as an attachment with javamail, you need the bytes from say a jpg or bmp.  What you'll need to do is send the model, eg the coordinates, to the server and recreate the image server side.  Perhaps a html5 canvas has direct support for outputting the images as bytes, I don't know, but that would help.  In that case you'd simply transfer those bytes to the server for attaching to the mail.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Canvas has a cool api trick to do this:

```
 var encodedImage = canvas1.toDataURL();  //this generates base64 encoded image in png

   //for jpeg 
   var encodedImage = canvas1.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Now you can store that encodedImage in back-end in a table or file. If you want to show it on a page, just assign it back to html img tag to source property